# Where can I find CLI specification?

Tags: c#, .net, specifications

I am looking for CLI specification.
Where can I find it to download?

Comment: I simply don't understand upvoting (or asking) this question when a google search for "CLI Specification" returns the correct result first, and plenty of supporting information on the first page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not ask google?

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Answer (score 7):

I think you're after [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole host of C# and CLI specification documents [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx).